# How to call a method of super class form subclass SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, textures, skspritenode

I subclass the `SKSpriteNode` to create a `SKButton` in `SKButton.h`

```
@interface SKButton : SKSpriteNode
```

now I want to change the button image by method in `SKButton.m`

```
self = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:image];
```

here self is `SKButton` but it is giving me error

> Cannot assign to 'self' outside of a method in the init family
>   Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'SKButton *' from 'SKSpriteNode *'

I also tried this in `SKButton.m`

```
self = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:image];
```

It gives me error

> No visible @interface for 'SKButton' declares the selector
>   'spriteNodeWithImagedNamed:'

Comment: You need to change the `texture` property. You cannot reassign `self` to a new objet instance, which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @0x141E its same as `self = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:image];`

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please show me how to ?

Answer (score 2):

`spriteNodeWithImageNamed:` is a class method on `SKSpriteNode` that returns a new SKSpriteNode using the supplied image.  Essentially, what you are trying to do with this line -

```
self = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:image];
```

is change the current object into a new object - which you can't do. Even if you could, it would be a new `SKSpriteNode`, not a new `SKButton`.

What you need to do is manipulate the `texture` property of your node -

```
self.texture=[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:image];
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
self = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:image];
```

you are downcasting a `SKSpriteNode` to `SKButton` which is incorrect as a `SKSpriteNode` instance does not have the extra implementation provided by SKButton.

Since `SKButton` is a `SKSpriteNode` subclass it contains all its functionality so you can just do:

```
- (void)buttonClicked {
   [self setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:"buttonClicked.png"]];
}
```

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what you have said here without example

Comment: currently adding one:)

Comment: You can't assign a string to the `texture` property - you need to generate an `SKTexture` from the image name